# Pandas DataFrame Retrieve Value from Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposely I have dataframe as below:

```
Idx A B C
0   1 2 3
1   3 4 5
2   2 3 8
```

The max value of dataframe column B is 4, and I could get the index from `df["B"].argmax()` which is 1.

The problem is now, how could I get the exact max value of the dataframe column B?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
     A  B  C
Idx         
0    1  2  3
1    3  4  5
2    2  3  8

In [7]: df.max()
Out[7]: 
A    3
B    4
C    8
dtype: int64

In [10]: df['B'].max()
Out[10]: 4

In [8]: df.idxmax()
Out[8]: 
A    1
B    1
C    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yeap. Now, I have the index from df.idxmax(). How to use this index, to get the value of column A? I have tried something like df["A"](df.idxmax()), but it's not working? 

Thanks!

Comment: ``df['A'].max()`` or ``df['A'](df.idxmax()['A'])`` is much more verbose